# How to hide response in firebug console on ajax using mustache socket.io

Tags: jquery, ajax, socket.io, mustache, mustache.php

I tried several way to hide response on firebug console. i found woorank using mustache js, socket.io. there just "null" response. they using mustache template.

I'm trying to understand how all this work together , even not showing data in the response. or may update with sockets. please provide some example link so it help me to understand the whole concept

Comment: best place to go to the documentation first.

Comment: where to find documentation no idea ? please check https://www.woorank.com/en/www/nuldi.com no response in firebug